# A question on a proof of $C^1$ implies locally Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

I stumbled upon [this answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143781/180995) while studying the proposition that if $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is $C^1$ then $f$ is locally Lipschitz.

The answer in the link applies Taylor's theorem.

And I was wondering if one could alternatively argue using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Concretely,

> I wrote this proof and was wondering if someone could tell me if it is
>   correct?

Proof:

Let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be $C^1$ and let $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$. Since $f$ is $C^1$ its derivative $f'$ is continuous. Hence $f'$ attains a maximum $L$ on $\overline{B(x_0,1)}$. Then since

$$ f(x) - f(x_0) \stackrel{FTC}{=} \int_{x_0}^x f'(t) dt$$

we have

$$ \|f(x) - f(x_0)\| = \left \| \int_{x_0}^x f'(t) dt \right \| \le \int_{x_0}^x \|f'(t)\| dt \le L \|x-x_0\|$$

hence $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $B(x_0, 1)$.

Comment: This doesn’t make much sense unless $n =1$; otherwise what do you mean by prime notation?

Comment: You can fix this by restricting $f$ to the line through $x$ and $x_0$, and applying FTC there. Also, the answer you refer to uses FTC.

Comment: @Idisagree Oh, good point. Thank you for your comment. If you post it in an answer then I could upvote and accept since it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f\in C^1$, there exists a $\delta>0$, such that for $\|\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x_0}\|<\delta$, there is
$$
\left\|\dfrac{f(\overrightarrow{x})-f(\overrightarrow{x_0})}{\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x_0}}-f'(\overrightarrow{x_0})\right\|<1
$$
Since 
$$
\left\|\dfrac{f(\overrightarrow{x})-f(\overrightarrow{x_0})}{\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x_0}}-f'(\overrightarrow{x_0})\right\|\geqslant\left\|\dfrac{f(\overrightarrow{x})-f(\overrightarrow{x_0})}{\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x_0}}\right\|-\left\|f'(\overrightarrow{x_0})\right\|
$$
There is
$$
\left\|f(\overrightarrow{x})-f(\overrightarrow{x_0})\right\|<(\|f'(\overrightarrow{x_0})\|+1)\|\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x_0}\|=L|\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x_0}\|
$$
So $f$ is locally Lipschitz.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can choose a convex neigborhood $V$ of $x\in R^n $. Then, for every $y\in V$ you can define $\lambda(t)=f(x+ty)$, with $t \in [0, 1]$. Compute the $\lambda'(t)$, use the chain rule and the mean value inequality for vector valued functions with domain in $R$.